# BFC margin collapsed

Tags: html, css

I want to ask one question about BFC,please see my code:

```
<div  class="main">
   <div class="aside"></div>
</div>


.main{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  margin:100px 0;
}
.aside{
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px; 
  background-color: red;
  margin:100px 0;
}
```

Why are main can add new BFC(set css overflow:hidden;) but aside will not be able to add new BFC(set css `overflow:hidden;`) of it.BFC is also changing the way?

Comment: i means is that this code why not prevent margin collapsing,the code is:  .main{height: 200px;background-color: green;width: 300px;margin:100px 0;}
  .aside{width: 100px;height: 150px;background-color: red;margin:100px 0;overflow: hidden;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quote from [Visual formatting model](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a block formatting context collapse.

The margins collapse under the following three conditions:

1.Vertical

2.adjacent block-level boxes

3.in a BFC

The  `.aside` was styled `overflow: hidden` to generate a BFC for its descendants.However, it doesn't affect the layout outer the `.aside`. That is, the `.main` and the `.aside` are still in a BFC generated by the root element in this example, so the margins collapse.